# Unable to Automatically Install GCC for Cython from Python in a Dockerfile

Tags: c, python-3.x, docker, gcc, dockerfile

I'm facing an issue while working on my Python project that requires Cython as a dependency. In my Dockerfile, I have added a code snippet to check if Cython is a dependency and automatically install GCC if it's needed. However, it appears that GCC is not being installed or set up even when Cython is successfully installed.

Here's the relevant part of my Dockerfile:

```
# Check if Cython is a dependency and install GCC if needed
RUN poetry show cython >/dev/null 2>&1 && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc || true
```

My expectation was that if Cython is listed as a dependency in my project, GCC would be installed as well, as it's required for compiling C code generated by Cython. However, even when Cython is installed, GCC is not getting set up.

I've checked for error messages during the Docker build process, but I haven't received any. Additionally, I'm using base image `python:3.11.5-alpine3.18`

Comment: What is `poetry show`'s exit code if the package exists? If it doesn't exist?

Comment: alpine image doesn't have _apt-get_ it uses _apk_ package manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you trying to use *apt* package manager which doesn't exist on alpine distributions. You'll have to use *[apk](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Package_Keeper)* instead, so it will look something like this:

```bash
RUN poetry show cython >/dev/null 2>&1 && \
    apk update && apk add build-base || true
```

- *build-base* package will install *gcc* and relevant libraries, check out more info [here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/GCC)
- You can install *gcc* only with `apk add gcc` if you sure that you don't need other libs

I assume that you didn't see any errors in logs, because of this [combination of && and ||](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2015) there are some caveats.

Comment: Thanks for the code. is there a general way to install the `gcc` manager whether it is on Alpine or any other distribution?

Comment: I'm not sure, usually gcc is part of some other build package (such as _build-essentials_ on ubuntu, or _build-base_ mentioned above). I've never tried installing it in a distribution agnostic way. You can try [build](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC) but it much more complicated and time consuming than using package manager. Probably you can try using linuxbrew - https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux

Comment: Do you think I could make a multi-stage build from it with another base image from [GCC Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/gcc)

Comment: I'm not an expert with using _gcc_ but you can try, my guess it will run but you won't be able to compile some things without installing additional libs (depending on a distribution)